# Good memory leak tool for C++ in a ARMv5tejl

Tags: c++, linux, arm

I have been trying to understand any memory leak in my application which runs in a Freescale MX28 board with armv5.

I tried to explore valgrind but learned that it is not supporting armv5 rather armv7.

I am looking for any good tool to proceed with.

Comment: Does that mean that the source can't be built to execute on another target architecture? (x86, e.g.)

Comment: I once had the same problem for an embedded linux system (are you using linux on your target??). I simply couldn't compile and run valgrind on the target. Either your code is portable (or the parts in question) to let it run and test on an x86 based linux system, or you have to rely on one of the tools mentioned in @Brendan Shanks answer.

Comment: @ Brain, yeah it is built and can be executed only in my target which is armv5 and a freescale MX28 board.

Comment: @g-makulik yes i could not able to run the valgrin in the target device. I can build iwth ARM arch but when i moved it to my target is said illegal operation when i ran valgrind. kind of locked here...

Comment: @linuxdeveloper So you might try **Brendan Shanks'** suggestions. I think trying to get valgrind building correctly for your target system will be much harder than its worth it. Anyway you still might have the alternate option to try getting the code you want to be tested compiled on a linux system that can run valgrind properly (if you have real hardware dependencies, you might try to mock the drivers in a testing environment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this (fairly old but hopefully useful) Linux Journal article: [Memory Leak Detection in Embedded Systems](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6059)

Some of the tools it lists: [mtrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mtrace), [memwatch](http://www.linkdata.se/sourcecode/memwatch/), [dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com)

Comment: i am finding most of the tools for C support. Do you know some tools which support C++ with my above env setups ?

Comment: @linuxdeveloper I don't think it really matters that the tools primarily support C. C++ memory management will boil down to the glibc standard interfaces anyway.

Answer (score -1):

If it is possible to send output to the net from your system,then there is a C/C++ library that you can compile and link in with your code that gives you web browser based runtime visibility into how memory is being used in the system. E.g.total current memory used, whether memory is being corrupted, double deletes, mismatched new[]/delete, leaked, etc.

Does your system have an ethernet/tcp/ip/socket stack or RS232 serial port available to which output could be sent? If you have a serial port, there are gadgets that can do RS232<->TCP/IP
bidirectional communication.  You can also use a linux box with a serial port and some software that proxies between ethernet and RS232.

Let me know if you are interested in seeing this work on a linux/bsd/mac/windows box before trying it out on your embedded system.  Sample C++ buggy code with typical memory bugs is included, so essentially it is 'unzip' a file, do 'make' and watch the action in your desktop/smartphone browser. What OS is your Freescale MX28 board running?

Comment: I'd be interested in your solution. Where can I find it?